# Encoding an AudioBuffer with web codecs

Tags: web-audio-api, webcodecs

I'm trying to process audio files using the Web Audio API and then to encode the result using the Web Codecs API, here is what a simplified version of my code looks like:

```js
/**
 * Encode an audio file using web codecs
 */
async function encodeAudio(url: string) {
  const audioBuffer = await fetchAudioBuffer(url); // see function below
  const signal = bufferToF32Planar(audioBuffer); // see function below

  const encoder = new AudioEncoder({
    output: console.log,
    error: console.error,
  });

  encoder.configure({
    codec: 'opus',
    sampleRate: 44100,
    numberOfChannels: 2,
    bitrate: 128_000, // 128 kbps
  });

  const data = new AudioData({
    format: 'f32-planar',
    sampleRate: audioBuffer.sampleRate,
    numberOfChannels: audioBuffer.numberOfChannels,
    numberOfFrames: audioBuffer.length,
    timestamp: 0,
    data: signal,
  });

  encoder.encode(data);
}

/**
 * Convert an audio buffer into a planar float 32 array
 * @param input processed audio buffer
 * @returns Typed array
 */
function bufferToF32Planar(input: AudioBuffer): Float32Array {
  const result = new Float32Array(input.length * input.numberOfChannels);

  let offset = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < input.numberOfChannels; i++) {
    const data = input.getChannelData(i);
    result.set(data, offset);
    offset = data.length;
  }

  return result;
}

/**
 * Fetch the audio file and convert it into
 * an audio buffer using an audio context
 */
async function fetchAudioBuffer(
  input: RequestInfo | URL,
  init?: RequestInit | undefined,
): Promise<AudioBuffer> {
  const context = new AudioContext();
  const res = await fetch(input, init);
  const buffer = await res.arrayBuffer();

  return await context.decodeAudioData(buffer);
}

await encodeAudio('/audio.mp3');
```

However when I run this code, I'm getting the error `DOMException: Input audio buffer is incompatible with codec parameters`. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your source file has a different sample rate than 44.1 kHz. But you could use the Web Audio API to resample your source file when it gets decoded.

```js
const context = new AudioContext({ sampleRate: 44100 });
```

Calling `decodeAudioData()` on that `context` will then always produce an `AudioBuffer` at 44.1 kHz.